# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string' ngFor in Angular

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I got this error while trying to display an array of objects

```
Error: src/app/components/timeline/timeline.component.html:9:29 - error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.

<h4>{{publication.user.name}}</h4>
                          ~~~~

src/app/components/timeline/timeline.component.ts:10:15
10  templateUrl: './timeline.component.html',
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component TimelineComponent.
```

in my timeline.component.html I have this:

```
<div id="publications">
    <div *ngFor = "let publication of publications" class="item-publication">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h4>{{publication.user.name}}</h4>
            </div>

        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the getPublications function that I have

```
getPublications(page){

    this._publicationService.getPublications(this.token, page).subscribe(
        response => {
            
            console.log(response);
            if(response.publications){
                this.total = response.total_items;
                this.pages = response.pages;
                this.publications = response.publications;

                if(page > this.pages){
                    this._router.navigate(['/home']);
                }
            }else{
                this.status= 'error';
            }
            
        },

        error =>{
            var errorMessage = <any>error;
            console.log(errorMessage);
            if(errorMessage != null){
                this.status = 'error';
            }
        }


        );
}
```

If I make a console.log(response) it shows me the values of the array and the properties are correct (name,surname,email, text etc)

[image]

In the HTML code, when I do the loop for the publication's text `<h4>{{publication.text}}</h4>` it works and even if I use `<h4>{{publication.user}}</h4>` it shows a list of Objects.

I'm taking an online course and basically copying what the teacher does line by line but IDK why when I try to display name and surname properties, it shows the error that I told you

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using an interface?

Comment: No interface used here, just pure classes

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in a stack blitz?

Comment: Hi, I'm having an issue importing the projects  in Stackblitzit from Github "Something went wrong with this repository" But I got no errors while uploading it

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution and is related to [TS type system](https://blog.angular-university.io/typescript-2-type-system-how-does-it-really-work-when-are-two-types-compatible-its-actually-quite-different-than-other-type-systems/) so basically I have a model object called `publication.ts` which includes:

```
export class Publication{
constructor(

public _id:string,
public text: String,
public file: String,
public created_at: String,
public user: String 


){}
```

}

And the issue was related to the type for the property `user` so by changing its type to `public user: any` it worked and now it shows the required fields. Sorry for posting this without a deep search before ask for help. Newbie mistakes

Thanks for the help

Comment: That was exactly my mistake, so you solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing to the data so there is a small delay in getting the data. Wrap the tag with a *ngIf to wait for the data to be available.

```
<div *ngIf="publications" id="publications">
    <div *ngFor = "let publication of publications" class="item-publication">    
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h4 *ngIf="publication && publication.user && publication.user.name">{{publication.user.name}}</h4>
            </div>    
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work, I tried both but the same error message continues.

Comment: updated the code now it should not throw an error

Comment: Hi again, still doesn't work. Do you think that this is related to the way I'm getting the data from the backend? my object publication.js is using mongoose.Schema and I decleared a var called publicationSchema = Schema ({})  which includes this property `user: { type:Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}`

Comment: updated code again put an *ngIf="publications" on the outer div can you try that

Comment: you can always show the json inside the HTML by this - <span *ngIf="publication">{{ publication |  json}} </span> and then do this <span *ngIf="publication && publication.user">{{ publication.user | json}} </span> and finally this <span *ngIf="publication && publication.user && publication.user.name">{{ publication.user.name | json}} </span>

Comment: Hi, Actually, I found the solution and is related to TypeScript type system. I'll answer it but thank you so much for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234240/discussion-between-tfa-and-secaidadevstudent).